# How to display a single value from restful API using Express in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here i want to get the prices of the "id" that i pass through URL.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

let cars = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "cultus",
  price: 15000,
  color: "gray",
},
{
 id: 2,
 name: "corolla",
 price: 50000,
 color: "golden",
},
{
 id: 3,
 name: "mercedes",
 price: 100000,
 color: "black",
}
];

 app.get("/", function (req, res) {
 res.send("Hello World");
});

 app.get("/api/cars", function (req, res) {
 res.send(cars);
})

app.get("/api/cars/:id", (req, res) => {
let car = cars.find(c => c.id=== parseInt(req.params.id));

if (!car) return res.status(400).send("Product not found");
return res.send(car);
})

app.listen(3000);
```

What i want is that if i pass "id=1" in URL then only the price of that record should be displayed. And how to display all cars having price greater than the price passed through URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the price only using

```js
app.get("/api/cars/:id", (req, res) => {
let car = cars.find(c => c.id=== parseInt(req.params.id));
    
if (!car) return res.status(400).send("Product not found");
// only send price
return res.send({price: car.price});
})
```

Comment: you'd have to use [filter function on the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), say you have an endpoint where you get the price as a url parameter, filter the cars as `let filteredCars = cars.filter(c=> c.price > req.params.price); res.send(filteredCars);`

Comment: Hats off to you Sir. I was trying to solve it for a week.